# Flutter text fields and buttons become unclickable after deployment with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I built a simple logging app that takes a few values in text boxes and one checkbox, and when a button is pressed, adds them to a firestore database. This project was working completely as it was supposed to when testing, but after I deployed to firebase hosting, I cant select the textboxes, checkbox, or buttons, to use them I have to tab onto them to select them. Using this I was able to input values and hit the enter button, but it did not add anything to the database.

I tried again using flutter run and everything still worked, flutter doctor came back clean. I managed once somehow to get the deployed site to work, after submitting a log on the test app (flutter run) the deployed site started working and I could select and type everything and the submitted log was added to the database, but I cannot replicate this so I don't know how it happened.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.